# "Propositional logic" in italiano

Tags: translation, phrase-request, mathematics

In una discussione a proposito di questa [domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/11280/), si è menzionato quello che in inglese si conosce come "propositional logic" e mi è venuta la curiosità di sapere come si chiama in italiano. Mi riferisco a [questo](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1152/lectures/07/Slides07.pdf) (non ho ricercato molto, è uno dei primi documenti che mi è apparso da una veloce ricerca con Google).

Sulla [Wikipedia italiana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logica_proposizionale) ho visto l'espressione "logica proposizionale"
(la Wikipedia italiana, però, non sembra essere sempre affidabile e questo articolo non mi sembra particolarmente buono).

In questo [articolo dell'Enciclopedia Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/logica-matematica/), si trova l'espressione "logica degli enunciati".

La mia domanda è: qual è il modo (o i modi) standard di tradurre "propositional logic" in italiano?

Comment: Perlomeno nei termini di matematica in italiano non credo che ci siano differenze regionali (?). Nei miei due primi anni di università usavamo certi libri, traduzioni dall'inglese, da Limusa, una casa editrice messicana, che ci facevano ridere tutti per quanto trovavamo bizzarro il vocabolario riguardante concetti matematici (come, ad esempio, "vecindades" per "neighbourhoods", che io ho sempre sentito chiamare "entornos" nel mio paese – e in catalano "entorns" –). (Poi i libri tradotti non ci furono più).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facendo una ricognizione di libri e dispense che ho a casa, nel computer e in rete direi che si usino quasi a pari merito “logica/calcolo proposizionale” e “logica/calcolo degli enunciati”.

Ho consultato Bagni/Gorla/Labella, *Introduzione alla logica ed al linguaggio matematico*; Asperti/Ciabattoni, *Logica a informatica*; Palladino/Palladino, *Logiche non classiche*, Abbagnano, *Dizionario di filosofia*; e alcune dispense che ho in casa o che sono in rete.

<sub>La logica/calcolo dei predicati è invece strettamente più ampia di quella degli enunciati/proposizioni: introduce appunto i predicati e i quantificatori.</sub>

Comment: Infatti io stessa avevo appena cancellato "logica dei predicati" dalla domanda. Scusa per non averlo fatto prima. Credo di averlo cancellato nello stesso preciso momento in cui è arrivata la tua risposta :(